# 'Shot' or 'Filmed' to overcome its ambiguity?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, ambiguity

I thought of a sentence -

> Back then, Mr. Anderson *was shot* by a journalist when he was misbehaving with a woman.

The surprise is that I am talking about 'shot' with a camera and *not a gun!*

The context is clear. We are talking about the evidences against Mr. Anderson. Now, if I use that Mr. Anderson was 'filmed' by the journalist (to avoid misunderstanding), I feel that 'film' is a better word for 'video'. We often, looking at a picture, say 'Nice shot' because 'shot' represents a still photo and not a video.

Well, I can't use *'...was shot dead...'* because it's *not always* that a person dies after being shot!

Note: I'm talking **only** about a still photograph

Comment: I have a response. However, I do not understand why you included "Well, I can't use '...was shot dead...' because it's not always that a person dies after being shot! " How does this relate to the rest of the post?

Comment: Putting 'shot dead' clearly means that I'm talking about the murder of Mr. Anderson which is *not* the case and hence raise the ambiguity. I want to tell that Mr. Anderson was shot by a camera. Someone was *shot* could mean both - with a gun or with a camera.. Someone was *shot **dead*** only means shot by some weapon! @Max

Comment: [Shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_(filmmaking)) is also used in the film and video world.

Comment: But then I need to **add**... shot a video or shot a film further I guess! @ThePhoton On the other hand, if I say that I filmed something that certainly means 'video'.

Comment: I thought you were trying to make the sentence ambiguous? If you want to make it clear, why not say he was *photographed* by the journalist and be done with it?

Comment: @ThePhoton fully agreed (+1)..but trust me it just came to my mind and I asked here for a good reason. Actually it hailed from 'Nice shot' referring to a picture. I'm into photography these days...blame that for this! :)

Comment: "Filmed" does not imply "video", however "video" does imply "filmed".

Comment: Aside: **back then** is used to refer to an extended period of time in the past, synonymous with "in those days", and is used with circumstances or conditions that obtained throughout the period. "Back then, we didn't have color TV."  So that "Back then, he was shot while misbehaving..." is odd, at least to my ear.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It's a very unclear question that could be paraphrased "What is a verb meaning to take a still photograph of someone, as in *the photographer Xed John Smith*?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I didn't notice the edit: *Note: I'm talking only about a still photograph*.

*Filmed* would not work here since this implies capturing video, not images/photographs.

So, by default **shot** is your only choice between *shot* and *filmed*.

You might consider

> 1. [snap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snapped)
>
>    6. c (1) :  to take photographically
>         (2) :  to take a snapshot of
>
> Mr. Anderson was *snapped* by a journalist

But I think the best alternative that comes to mind is photographed.

> Mr. Anderson was **photographed** by a journalist

---

The answer below was given with the original post in mind, in which the focus seemed to be video, not photography.

---

I assume that from further context, the audience understands that we are talking in the present day.

> [film](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/filmed)
>
> 2. To record on film or video using a movie camera:
>      *film a rocket launch*; *film a scene from a ballet*.

*Filmed* seems perfectly natural to me, and it would remove the ambiguity. Interestingly, it's still commonly used despite the fact that cameras nowadays have no film! Here is an example: [*Lovesick Ghost Caught on Film*](http://www.travelchannel.com/shows/ghost-adventures/video/lovesick-ghost-caught-on-film).

I've heard *videoed* but it just doesn't seem to be as common as *filmed* in my experience. A quick search shows the difference in popularity.
[image]

*Recorded* or *taped* might work too. However, *recorded* and *taped* could be misinterpreted as *audio* evidence.

Now, using *filmed* removes the ambiguity but I think another common way to express this is

> 1. Mr. Anderson was *caught on film* by a journalist...

You can also use *tape*, *video*, or *camera*,

> 2. Mr. Anderson was *caught on tape* by a journalist...
> 3. Mr. Anderson was *caught on camera* by a journalist...
> 4. Mr. Anderson was *caught on video* by a journalist...

I would use 2, but 3. seems more popular. 
[image]

I don't think 2 is likely to be understood to be audio evidence since nowadays *caught on tape* is understood to mean *caught on video*, especially when something incredible or shocking happens. There was even a show called [*Shocking Behaviors: Caught on Tape*.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nBhVr5syqY)

If you really wanted to use *shot*, then you might consider saying *shot on camera*, but I think *caught on camera* sounds better. 
[image]

Interestingly, we say that vidoes are "shot in HD".

Comment: caught on tap means still photography?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. No, I don't think _tape_ can refer to a photograph. Were you looking for another way to say "photographed", because it sounded like you were interested in expressing video.

Comment: If you *must* use the word shot - because there are more appropriate words than this - why not just say 'Mr. Anderson was shot on camera by a journalist when he was misbehaving with a woman' You can even make it more explicit by choosing to bracket off [on camera].

Comment: @tom Honestly, a more normal way of saying that would be to say "*Mr. Anderson was **caught** on camera by a journalist...*".

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what is and isn't a suggested answer here. *Shoot* or *shot* is often used of films (motion pictures) and video images, so wouldn't really work for the OP's restrictions: "to take a picture or series of pictures or television images of : PHOTOGRAPH, FILM" ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoot)). Caught on camera is appropriate here because it normally means photographed without permission or warning (if you catch an animal you typically don't have its permission, and the same principle applies) but isn't always a synonym.